# Analyzing quick sort in C

Tags: c

What I am trying to do is get the desired output below. I have tried printing in the beginning of quicksort and I am getting some of the correct values but I feel my whole approach is not working so I need some help.

**level partitionNumber d [3a_spaces x1 x3 ... xn 3b_spaces]**

*Where*:

**level** is the level of recursion.

**partitionNumber** is the number used to create the partition.

**d** is '>' if partitionNumber is greater than the elements of the
partition otherwise is '<'.

**3a_space** is a set of 3 space characters for each element of the
array before the start of the partition.

**x1 x3 ... xn** is the set of number in the partition. Note: print
these numbers using the "%3d" format descriptor.

**3b_spaces** is a set of 3 space characters for each element of the
array after the end of the partition.

desired output:

```
1  0  [23 13 82 33 51 17 45 75 11 27 ]
2 51> [27 13 33 23 17 45 11          ]
3 23> [11 13 17                      ]
3 23> [11 13 17                      ]
3 23< [            33 45 27          ]
4 45> [            27 33             ]
4 45> [            27 33             ]
3 23< [            27 33 45          ]
2 51> [11 13 17 23 27 33 45          ]
2 51< [                        82 75 ]
2 51< [                        75 82 ]
1  0  [11 13 17 23 27 33 45 51 75 82 ]
```

my output:

```
1  0  [23 13 82 33 51 17 45 75 11 27 ]
2 51> [27 13 33 23 17 45 11          ]
3 23> [11 13 17                      ]
2 13> [11 13 17                      ]
3 23< [            33 45 27          ]
4 45> [            27 33             ]
3 27? [            27 33             ]
2 45> [            27 33 45          ]
1 23> [11 13 17 23 27 33 45          ]
2 51< [                        82 75 ]
1 82> [                        75 82 ]
0 51> [11 13 17 23 27 33 45 51 75 82 ]






 #include<stdio.h>

int inputLine[10];

void quicksort(int v[], int left, int right, int level, int previousPivotPoint, char d);

int main()
{
  int v[] = { 23, 13, 82, 33, 51, 17, 45, 75, 11, 27 };
  quicksort(v, 0, 9, 0, -1, ' ');



  return 0;
}

void swap(int v[], int i, int j)
{
  int temp;
  temp = v[i];
  v[i] = v[j];
  v[j] = temp;
}

void quicksort(int v[], int left, int right, int level, int previousPivotPoint, char d)
{
  int i, last;

  level++;
  if (previousPivotPoint > v[left]) d = '>';
  else if (previousPivotPoint < v[left]) d = '<';


  if (left >= right)
  {
    level--;
    return;
  }
  if (previousPivotPoint == -1)
  {
    printf("%d  0  [", level);
  } else
  {
    printf("%d %d%c [", level, previousPivotPoint, d);
  }

  previousPivotPoint = v[(left + right) / 2];

  d = '?';
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
    if (i > right || i < left)
    {
      printf("   ");
    } else
    {
      printf("%d ", v[i]);
    }
  }
  printf("]\n");

  swap(v, left, (left + right) / 2);

  last = left;

  for (i = left + 1; i <= right; i++)
  {
    if (v[i] < v[left])
    {
      last++;
      swap(v, last, i);
    }
  }

  swap(v, left, last);
  quicksort(v, left, last - 1, level, previousPivotPoint, d);
  quicksort(v, last + 1, right, level, previousPivotPoint, d);
  level--;


  if (previousPivotPoint > v[left]) d = '>';
  else if (previousPivotPoint < v[left]) d = '<';
  printf("%d %d%c [", level, previousPivotPoint, d);
  previousPivotPoint = v[(left + right) / 2];


  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
    if (i > right || i < left)
    {
      printf("   ");
    } else
    {
      printf("%d ", v[i]);
    }
  }
  printf("]\n");

}
```

Comment: "I feel my whole approach is not working" - can you elaborate on this? What is it you don't think works? What is it you want it to do that it doesn't? It seems very cool to me (prints, sorts...)

Comment: Oh, i see - well that is a very different story!

Answer (score 2):

A couple things I notice:

1. If level is going to be a modular variable instead of one passed in to the quick sort routine, it's unlikely to ever go down. Consider incorporating it into the signature of your quick sort function.
2. You start at `i = left` - this won't print your whole original underlying array. Consider always going over the array and printing them all, checking if you're in the current array or not.
3. You make a FORWARD declaration `void swap(int v[], int i, int j);` inside your quicksort routine. What's up with that? **Note:** apparently it's from K&R. As a matter of personal taste, I'm not the biggest fan of the notation, but you could do worse than following K&R, eh?

Comment: You have `if (i > right)` but you never check the left side. Consider making this `if (i > right || i <= left)` or something along those lines (it might be `<` not `<=`, but you can figure that out :-)).

Comment: As for why you have extra iterations, that I'm not sure. The reason for that doesn't jump out at me just by reading.

Comment: Ok code has been updated and I have figured out the partition number problem

Comment: @mateo if incorporate the suggestion in my first comment (about the right/left) you will it much easier to spot the problems.

Comment: I have made considerable progress and am almost done except for a few minor things as seen in my output. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Didn't have time to delve into your code too deeply but here are a few
things.

First thing you should do is replace that hardcoded `10` with a
`#define` constant.

It should not come as a surprise that you didn't set the value of `d`,
hence all the spaces. Also, why make `d` global?

Your print loop should traverse the entire list so the part in
brackets will always be the same size.

Comment: I believe he does set the value of d, on line 8 (assuming the #define statement is line 1) `char d = ' ';`  It's a global 'constant' meaning a space (presumably d for delimiter?)

Comment: In the desired output d is either > or < to show that ( on the second line of output) that 51 is greater than the numbers to the right of it

Comment: Ah - in that case, yes it shouldn't be a modular variable - it should be declared only in the most necessary scope, which presumably is the function.